# Removing submatrix from numpy array by shifting other elements

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose i have a numpy array

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [3,4,5,6],
              [2,3,4,4],
              [3,3,1,2]])
```

I want to delete the submatrix [[3,4],[3,1]]. I can do it as follows

```
mask = np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)  
mask[2:,1:-1] = False
a_new = a[mask,...]
print(a) #output array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 2])
```

However, i want the output as

```
np.array([[1,2,3,4],
          [3,4,5,6],
          [2,4,0,0],
          [3,2,0,0]])
```

I just want numpy to remove the submatrix and shift others elements replacing the empty places with 0. How can i do this?

Comment: gonna need a [mcve].  How is the submatrix defined?

Comment: the submatrix is defined through a slice as shown in example ie. mask[2:,1:-1]=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find a function that does what you ask, but combining `np.roll` with a mask with this routine produces your output. Perhaps there is a more elegant way:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [3,4,5,6],
              [2,3,4,4],
              [3,3,1,2]])

mask = np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)
mask[2:,1:-1] = False

mask2 = mask.copy()
mask2[2:, 1:] = False
n = 2 #shift length

a[~mask2] = np.roll((a * mask)[~mask2],-n)
a
>>array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [3, 4, 5, 6],
   [2, 4, 0, 0],
   [3, 2, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: it does work indeed. However, like u said maybe there is a better way. For the time being this solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply update those element entries to be zero.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [3,4,5,6],
              [2,3,4,4],
              [3,3,1,2]])

a[2:, 2:] = 0
```

returns

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that is not what i want. look at the example and expected output i have given.